# zsh gsed command not found

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh

I am using oh my zsh. I am not able to use some commands which I could do on ubuntu for e.g.. \s in regular expressions. I installed home-brew and then `brew install gnu-sed --default-names` but still I am unable to used sed command. my $PATH variable is a bit messed up and I am not sure how to correct it. `/Users/ishansrivastava/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin`. **What should I do so that I can use all gnu commands without hassle on my Mac?** also please give me the list of commands on which I have to use gnu command instead of default for e.g..gsed instead of sed etc

Answer (score 0):

All rely on how you define your path, the first paths you add are the ones that going to be used first, for example:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$HOME/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$HOME/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/share/bin:$PATH:$HOME/projects/go/bin:$HOME/.cargo/bin"
```

That expands to:

```
$ echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}

/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
/Users/<user>/Library/Python/2.7/bin
/Users/<user>/Library/Python/3.6/bin
/Users/<user>/node_modules/.bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/share/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/go/bin
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
/Users/<user>/go_appengine
/Users/<user>/google-cloud-sdk/bin
/Users/<user>/projects/go/bin
/Users/<user>/.cargo/bin
/Users/<user>/.fzf/bin
```

In this case, for example, you can notice I give priority to python2 instead of python3 and after that, if my command is not found it will use `/usr/local/bin`, then `/usr/local/sbin` and so on.

In your case just ensure that the parent path of the commands that you want to use as a "priority" is on top, before the other paths.